# Variational Principle for Free Particle Motion (Relativistic)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

This is the same problem as someone asked before: [Problem understanding something from the variational principle for free particle motion (James Hartle's book, chapter 5)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/551796/292828)

The question below:

Here is the problem. First, we have
$$L = \biggl[\biggl(\frac{dt}{d\sigma}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{dx}{d\sigma}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{dy}{d\sigma}\biggr)^2 - \biggl(\frac{dz}{d\sigma}\biggr)^2\biggr]^\frac{1}{2} \tag{5.57}$$
then,
$$-\frac{d}{d\sigma}\biggl(\frac{\partial L}{\partial(dx^\alpha/d\sigma)}\biggr) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\alpha} = 0 .\tag{5.58}$$
And considering that $x^1 = x$ we conclude that
$$\frac{d}{d\sigma}\biggl[\frac{1}{L}\frac{dx^1}{d\sigma}\biggr] = 0. \tag{5.60}$$

I can't understand how eq (5.60) came. I don't know how he got this equation. I tried solving this, but I can't get the equation. Even a hint on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the notation of writing $L = \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}}$ is clear as this makes the following calculations very compact.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}\right)^{-1/2}\times 2\dot{x}^{\alpha} = \frac{\dot{x}^{\alpha}}{L}
\end{equation}
The above is just a consequence of chain rule. To be explicit the Minkowski metric was introduced $\eta_{\mu\nu} = diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$ and $\dot{x}^{\alpha}= \frac{d x^{\alpha}}{d \sigma}$. Also $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^{\alpha}} = 0$. The answer they proved follows.

Comment: Got it and also $\dot{x}^{\alpha}$ should be a total derivative, not partial, right?

Comment: Yes as the coordinates are parametrised by one parameter - the affine parameter $\sigma$. Have edited my answer accordingly.